# javascript getTime() to 10 digits only

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am using the following function to get the Time using javascript:

```
function timeMil(){
    var date = new Date();
    var timeMil = date.getTime();

    return timeMil;
}
```

And the value I get is:

> 1352162391299

While in PHP, I use the `time();` function to get Time and the value I get is

```
1352162391
```

How do I convert the value of javascript time to remove the last 3 digits and make it 10 digits only.

> From 1352162391299 
> To     1352162391
>   
> So that the Javascript time is the same with the PHP time.

Comment: I am using a **WAMP** server(_development_) that's why the user and server time are the same.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you just have to divide it by 1000 milliseconds and you'll get time in seconds

```
Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000)
```

Comment: but when ticks goes above one more digit, this would fail right?

Answer (score 7):

If brevity is ok, then:

```
function secondsSinceEpoch() {
    return new Date/1000 | 0;
}
```

Where:

- `new Date` is equivalent to `new Date()`
- `| 0` truncates the decimal part of the result and is equivalent to `Math.floor(new Date/1000)` (see [What does |0 do in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367264/what-does-0-do-in-javascript)).

Using newer features, and allowing for a Date to be passed to the function, the code can be reduced to:

```
let getSecondsSinceEpoch = (x = new Date) => x/1000 | 0;
```

But I prefer function declarations as I think they're clearer.

Comment: So that's cool, but an explanation of what or'ing with zero does would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try dividing it by 1000, and use parseInt method.

```
const t = parseInt(Date.now()/1000);

console.log(t);
```

Comment: but, parseInt only takes a string. `Date.now()/1000` is a number

Answer (score 2):

```
function ts() {
    return parseInt(Date.now()/1000);

}
```

Comment: but, parseInt only takes a string. `Date.now()/1000` is a number

Answer (score 0):

You could divide by 1000 and use `Math.floor()` on JavaScript.