# What does |0 do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

I have been looking into asm.js to use for a project recently, and I noticed that very often the asm.js compiled code will end a statement with `|0;`, even seemingly redundantly as in the statement `i = i|0;`

This is not something I have encountered in Javascript code before. What is it for?

**EDIT**

I don't believe this is duplicate. I know what a bitwise or is. I am specifically asking here why one might use it to or with a 0 before assignment. What purpose does that serve?

Comment: just see doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR

Comment: @Grundy I know what a bitwise or is. I just didn't understand the purpose of it in this case.

Comment: so, see duplicated question

Comment: from doc: _Bitwise ORing any number x with 0 yields x. Bitwise ORing any number x with -1 yields -1._

Comment: You can write it even shorter: `i |= 0`

Comment: @StephanBijzitter shorter on one symbol? :-)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Bitwise OR with 0 is more specific than bitwise OR. And the accepted answer explains that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert to integer and apply a bitwise or with `0`. Basically a short form of `Math.floor()`.

Comment: Note that `undefined` `NaN` and `null` are also turned into `0` with this! :-)