# How to convert Date into Timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to convert date into timestamp

I have two different format of date `Wed May 31 2017 15:33:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and `2017-05-31T10:03:47.592Z`. I want
to convert it into timestamp like `1379426880000`.

This is my code.

```
var noOfDays = 5;
var targetDate = new Date();

targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - noOfDays);
console.log("targetDate date is " + targetDate); //Wed May 31 2017 15:33:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
console.log(JSON.stringify(targetDate)); // "2017-05-31T10:03:47.592Z"
```

Comment: you can use moment.js https://momentjs.com/

Comment: `targetDate.valueOf()` gives you the timestamp in milliseconds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert date to timestamp in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873197/convert-date-to-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: @EvanSebastian : `targetDate.valueOf()` is converting my date into timestamp but it's `1494135757264` of 13 Digit, while the timestamp which stores in my DB is `1496679262` of 10 digit. whats's that last 3 digit stand for

Comment: It's seconds vs milliseconds

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to get the timestamp.

```
targetDate.getTime()
```

Comment: `targetDate.getTime()` is converting my date into timestamp but it's `1494135757264` of 13 Digit, while the timestamp which stores in my DB is `1496679262` of 10 digit. whats's that last 3 digit stand for

Comment: Please visit this link may provide a solution to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242828/javascript-gettime-to-10-digits-only/13242834