# How to get 10 digit timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have referred to the link [javascript getTime() to 10 digits only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242828/javascript-gettime-to-10-digits-only/13242834). And I got to know the way to convert date to 10 digit timestamp. My requirement is that I want last month date timestamp. Below is the code that I have tried:

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
var monthLastDay = Math.floor(lastDay.getTime()/1000);
console.log(monthLastDay);
```

When I run above code I get output: 1527705000. And when I check the output on https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php. I got

```
1527705000
Is equivalent to:
05/30/2018 @ 6:30pm (UTC)
```

Which I think is not correct as the month 05 has 31 days. So I should timestamp as 05/31/2018.

**EDIT:**

If I try with below code:

```
var date = new Date('6/8/2018');
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
var monthLastDay = Math.floor(lastDay.getTime()/1000);
console.log(monthLastDay);
```

I get output: 1530297000 which is equal to 6/29/2018. But output should be 6/30/2018.

Let me know possible solution to get the correct 10 digit timestamp.

Comment: `new Date()` is not trustable. Most browsers skip milliseconds in time stamp

Comment: @GeorgeBailey no one’s interested in milliseconds here as far as I can tell. They _want_ seconds, that’s why the division by 1000.

Comment: getMonth returns the date 0 based, so getMonth()+1 is the first day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with your timezone.

```
> new Date('6/8/2018')
Fri Jun 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
> new Date('6/8/2018').getTime()
1528408800000 // which is 06/07/2018 @ 10:00pm (UTC)
```

You should build the date in UTC if you want to use the timestamp as is

```
> var date = new Date('6/8/2018');
> Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
1530316800000 // which is 06/30/2018 @ 12:00am (UTC)
```